# Install and enable a Firefox extension from the command line

Tags: firefox

I'm working on a script that starts a new Firefox instance in a completely new profile. This works fine, but I also want this new profile to have some extensions automatically installed.

I tried to follow the standard procedure, which is to move the .xpi file to $PROFILEDIR/extensions/extension_id.xpi. This kind of works, so far as the extension appears in the Extensions page in Firefox. However, it is disabled, requiring to manually click on it and then click "Enable" in the popup that appears.

Do you know if it is possible to do this entire procedure programatically?